# Make Tab.Navigator disappears on login page

Tags: react-native

So... I have this login screen where is not been validated (I still don't need it to be)

When the user clicks "Acessar" I need it to be redirected to "Feed de Imagens", this is working at the moment, so what i want is to make the bottom bar don't appear when the user is at the login page.

**barraDeNavegacao.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
//import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import PaginaPrincipal from '../pages/paginaPrincipal';
import Mais from '../pages/mais';
import TirarFoto from '../pages/tirarFoto'
import Login from '../pages/login';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();


export default function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>     
      <Tab.Screen name="TirarFoto" component={TirarFoto} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Tirar Uma Foto' }} />
      
      <Tab.Screen name="Mais" component={Mais}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Mais' }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function BarraDeNavegacao() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stacl.Screen name="PaginaPrincipal" component={PaginaPrincipal} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Feed de Imagens' }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default BarraDeNavegacao;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import BarraDeNavegacao from './components/barraDeNavegacao'
import Login from './pages/login'
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {

  return (
    <>    
      <NavigationContainer>
        <BarraDeNavegacao />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs [Hiding tab bar in specific screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/). You will need a parent navigator to the `TabNavigator` and the `Login` screen

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I did it but how can I use the other function that i created?
it says:
Only one default export allowed per module. (36:0)

I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The most common pattern for achieving this is to create a screen that is at at same level as your tab navigation screen rather than being a child of it so you can navigate to a different stack that does not have the tabs. This is sometimes called the full screen modal pattern.

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is the home screen!</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyModal')}
        title="Open Modal"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Details</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ModalScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Dismiss" />
    </View>
  );
}

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

function MainStackScreen() {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <MainStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function RootStackScreen() {
  return (
    <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal">
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainStackScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen name="MyModal" component={ModalScreen} />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

More details here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/
and an expo snack example [here](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Opening%20a%20full-screen%20modal%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.8.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.13%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.7.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E3.10.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.14.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Ffull-screen-modal.js)